# select values that are larger than its sub-categorical average using sql

Tags: sql

For example, I have a table T like this:

```
sales | sub_category | name

10      A             phone
3       A             earphone
54      B             chair
23      C             popcorn
1       D             paper_clip
5       E             Diet_coke
```

I want to find sales that are higher than its sub_category. In this case it would be the first one.
I tried

```
SELECT AVG(sales), sub_category
FROM T
GROUP BY sub_category
```

which only gives me the average group by their sub_category. So I have problem doing the next step which is comparing each value to its categorical average. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may join the same table once again and then filter out necessary rows:

```sql
SELECT t.sales,t.sub_category,t.name,x.avg_sales
FROM t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(sales) AS avg_sales, sub_category
    FROM t
    GROUP BY sub_category
) x USING (sub_category)
WHERE t.sales > x.avg_sales;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! What does `using` do? When I put it in the query throws me an error.

Comment: It's the same as `ON t.sub_category = x.sub_category`

Answer (score 1):

We can use **with** clause or temporary tables: (with clause is supported by oracle)

Query:

```
WITH avg_sale as
(
SELECT AVG(sales) as average_sale, sub_category
FROM T
GROUP BY sub_category
)
select t.sales,t.sub_category,t.name,avg_sale.average_sale from t join avg_sale on (t.sub_category = avg_sale.sub_categroy) where avg_sale.average_sale<t.sales;
```